# Font issues - not taking in consideration the weight and line-height issues

Tags: css, sass

I want to use a custom font, so I added the cod below:

I verified the fonts path and is correct.

The font weight is ignored. If I ad another font to the familly, as Arial until it loads, it just takes only Arial.

1.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gop;
  src: url("../fonts/gop/normal/gop.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/gop/normal/gop.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/gop/normal/gop.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/gop/normal/gop.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/gop/normal/gop.svg#gop") format("svg");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400; }

@font-face {
  font-family: gop;
  src: url("../fonts/gop/bold/gop.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/gop/bold/gop.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/gop/bold/gop.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/gop/bold/gop.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/gop/bold/gop.svg#gop") format("svg");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700; }


h1 {
font: 700 1.875rem Gop;
}

p{
font: 400 1.875rem Gop;
```

}

---

2. If in reset I have:

`html * { 
  line-height: 1.15
}`

and later:

`h1  { 
  line-height: 1.5
}`

The line-height for h1 is ignored.

Comment: Wrap font-family `value` with double or single quote. Have you used  `length` or `percentage` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your "font:" lines are formatted slightly off, try adding "normal" in front:

```
font: normal 700 1.875rem Gop;
```

Single-line font shorthand reference (order matters):
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/

Generally speaking, separating font declaration into separate lines is better, ex:

```
font-family: Gop;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 1.875rem;
```

This is a bit longer but easier to work out problems. Which leads to the second issue ...

2) You need to specify ALL of the attributes when using a CSS shorthand, otherwise they will go back to the defaults.

Info about this here:
https://css-tricks.com/accidental-css-resets/

So you would need to include the line-height in your font:

```
font: normal 700 1.875rem/1.5 Gop;
```

This isn't an issue if you separate it into separate lines, with font-family, font-weight, etc.